# Set the default option for 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy Always'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, external

I've just started a new project in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) and the new project is using a fair amount of images/text files.

The actual project is a simple installer but my requirements are too advanced for existing installers so I'm having to create my own.

My issue is that I'm having to go into the properties of each file I have added and change the 'Copy to Output Directory' from 'Never' to 'Copy Always' and as you can imagine this is taking a fair bit of time with around 50 files to add:

[image]

Is it possible to set the 'Copy Always' as the default for adding new files to any [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) project? If so, how?

I imagine that there is some registry tweak that can do this, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: why don't you just unload the project file and edit the project file directly?

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden That solution is kind of.. clunky. I want to this to be the default for *every fi It just occured to me that this could probably be done via a macro.

Comment: Just don't do this one file at a time.  You can select more than one file in the Solution Explorer window.  Hold down the Shift or Ctrl key while clicking.  Basic workflow is selecting the first image file, then Shift+Click the last image file.  Changes you make in the Properties window apply to all the selected files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed @Hans Passant's comment about selecting *all* files and setting them to 'Copy Always', as per se:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work; still I'd check a few random files to make sure!